# Displaying Logged-In User Name and avatar in Wordpress Menu

Tags: php, functions, avatar

I want show the avatar user and username with this code.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_dynamic_menu_items' );
function my_dynamic_menu_items( $menu_items ) {
    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( strpos($menu_item->title, '#profile_name#') !== false) {
                $menu_item->title =  str_replace("#profile_name#",  wp_get_current_user()->user_login, $menu_item->title);
        }
    }

    return $menu_items;
}
```

The username is work but i don't known add avatar.

Can you help me please

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**get_avatar**" function to display avatar in menu with user name. Please try code given below:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_dynamic_menu_items', 10 );
function my_dynamic_menu_items( $menu_items ) {
    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( strpos($menu_item->title, '#profile_name#') !== false) {
            $menu_item->title =  str_replace("#profile_name#", wp_get_current_user()->user_login .' '. get_avatar( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, 50), $menu_item->title);
        }
    }
    return $menu_items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tiny plugin to do just this as I didn't find a nice wordpressy way of doing it. I intend it to work across different themes and with different membership plugins. I have been using Ultimate Member on Divi theme. Feel free to use it or adapt it as required. I hope that you find it helpful: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/logged-in-as/